# Ubuntu 18.04 configured as Samba Domian Controller takes a wrong turn, How can I rectify this Issue?

Tags: 18.04, server

I had setup an ubuntu 18.04 system as samba domian controller with help of this command

```
samba-tool domain provision
```

After that I check the system with following command

```
samba-tool domain level show
```

and it gives me an output

*Forest function level: (Windows) 2008 R2
Domain function level: (Windows) 2008 R2
Lowest function level of a DC: (Windows) 2008 R2*

everything works fine, but after few updates or some changes I was unable to connect any windows to this domain which I done earlier with no effort

so I check again with

`samba-tool domain level show` and out put is

*Forest function level: (Windows) 2008 R2
Domain function level: (Windows) 2008 R2
Lowest function level of a DC: (Windows) 2008 R2*

I also check with this following commands which I use earlier

`ping -c3 ub.lan` where **ub.lan** is my domian name and its output is

*ping: ub.lan: System error*

`ping -c3 tub.ub.lan` and the out put is

*PING tub (192.168.2.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from tub (192.168.2.100): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
64 bytes from tub (192.168.2.100): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
64 bytes from tub (192.168.2.100): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.041 ms
--- tub ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2032ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.041/0.041/0.042/0.007 ms*

`ping -c3` tub output is

*PING tub (192.168.2.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from tub (192.168.2.100): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.045 ms
64 bytes from tub (192.168.2.100): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms
64 bytes from tub (192.168.2.100): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.041 ms
--- tub ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2055ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.041/0.044/0.048/0.008 ms*

`host -t A ub.lan` output is

*Host ub.lan not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)*

*host -t A tub.ub.lan* output is

*Host tub.ub.lan not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)*

`host -t SRV _kerberos._udp.ub.lan` output is

*Host _kerberos._udp.ub.lan not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)*

`host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.ub.lan` output is

*Host _ldap._tcp.ub.lan not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)*

Earlier every command give correct messages. but now its all gone . is there any way to make things correct without reinstalling the os ? Please give me any sort of hints or suggestions for the above problem. Thanks in advance.

My /etc/nsswitch.conf

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat winbind
group:          compat winbind
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns myhostname winbind
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

> All the above commands are taken from google searchs.

Comment: Obviously seems to be a dns problem, is Samba actually running on the DC ? Does it have a fixed ipaddress ? does the first nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf point to the DC's ipaddress ?

Comment: Yes the system have a fixed IP address. Samba is running cause I can access it shares in network. I removed the resolv.conf and recreated with help from google and now it has content as 
nameserver 127.0.0.53
search trilliant.local
options edns0

Comment: I added /etc/nsswitch.conf on my question. @Rowland Penny

Comment: Your DC must be authoritative for its dns domain, so I would turn systemd-resolve off, create a new /etc/resolve.conf containing 'search ub.lan' and 'nameserver <THE_DC_IPADDRESS>'. Remove everything after 'files' on the 'hosts' in nsswitch.conf and replace it with 'dns'. see if that helps.